# How can I enforce that a template parameter used implements some interface in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, interface

I don't think this is possible in C++, what options do I have to simulate the behavior?

Comment: Do you mean interface in the java way (that is it inherits abstract base class X), or do you simply mean that it supports a set of operations?

Comment: If you try to use the interface, you will surely notice if it is absent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::is_base_of<YourInterface, YourParameter>`, and make an error if the result is `false`. Remember this is C++11.

Answer (score 11):

Use `std::is_base_of` as:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<IMyInterface, T>::value, 
                  "T must derive from IMyInterface");
};
```

You can same in function template as well.

Answer (score 3):

Some polymorphic interface or some static interface?
The latter can be checked by [Boost Concepts](http://www.boost.org/libs/concept_check/).

Comment: IMO this should be selected as the correct answer. If someone has already an interface that could be checked with std::is_base_of, so he does not need a template parameter. The feature allowing to specify "template interface" is called "Concepts" and no, currently it is not supported by C++. It was supposed to be a part of C++11 but did not made it in. The C++1y will probably have it. For now you can go around with something like the mentioned Boost Concept.